# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'testId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I'm trying to call an action in my controller:

using this url:
`http://localhost:5345/ManageTest/Details/5`

```
[Authorize]
public class ManageTestController : Controller
{

public ActionResult Details(int testId)
    {
```

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'testId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in 'MAMAdmin.Controllers.ManageTestController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That looks like you're trying to map to the default route, which is:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

To do that, change your parameter name in your `ActionResult` to be `id`:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
```

Otherwise you'd have to use the URL:

```
 http://localhost:5345/ManageTest/Details?testId=5
```

Comment: @DarrenDavies Haha, I had a week off work mate so I didn't use it (except logging in for the Fanatic badge) :)

Comment: THANKS! Finally an answer that is not "you're not passing the parameter in the http request". This answer should receive the cumulative upvotes of all the other, similar answers since it actually contains the correct implementation.

Comment: @Luc No problems, glad it helped you :)